# What is changing my $PATH variable? I don't want all of these extra directoriesT

Tags: path

I am new to Linux and am having trouble finding answers that make sense to me.

My /etc/environment folder is different than what my $PATH variable is. I want to "start fresh" with the default settings for my $PATH, since I was messing with it without knowing what I was doing. What could be modifying my $PATH variable? There are some added folders that look like they are from Miniconda3, Java, and Oracle.

Here are the outputs from my /etc/environment file

```
(base) eli@eli-XPS-13-7390-2-in-1:~$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
```

Here is my .profile

```
(base) eli@eli-XPS-13-7390-2-in-1:~$ cat .profile
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
fi
```

Here is my .bashrc

```
(base) eli@eli-XPS-13-7390-2-in-1:~$ cat .bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/eli/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/eli/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/eli/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="$PATH:/home/eli/miniconda3/bin"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Here is my $PATH

```
(base) eli@eli-XPS-13-7390-2-in-1:~$ echo $PATH
/home/eli/miniconda3/bin:/home/eli/miniconda3/condabin:/home/eli/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/db/bin
```

Where are all these extra folders coming from?! Is there anything else that could be modifying my $PATH? How do I get rid of whatever is adding these?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Anything in `/etc/profile.d` ?

Comment: Well, the miniconda stuff seems to come from the end of your .bashrc file at least.. .

Comment: @Kusalananda it looks like it, but what's in the .bashrc file should be appending the miniconda3 directory (once) but what's happening is that it is being appended (twice)

Comment: No. Note that `/home/eli/miniconda3/bin` and `/home/eli/miniconda3/condabin` are two different directory paths.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov wow! Yes, there are a few files in there, and one of them modifies /usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle/db/bin ; I deleted these two files, but my $PATH remains the same even after exporting the new $PATH I want in another session. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Kusalananda still, what I see at the end of the .bashrc file is only dealing with 1 of them (/home/eli/miniconda3/bin) and it should be appending it instead of pre-pending it. Am I missing something that you are seeing?

Comment: That `export` (`export PATH="$PATH:/home/eli/miniconda3/bin"`) is only executed if the command used in the assignment to `__conda_setup` wasn't successful, and `/home/eli/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` doesn't exist.